# How to know when log4j created a new log file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

Currently I am using log4j2, in my java application, I would like to know if it is possible to have a listener, for when a new file is generated (either because it exceeded the weight, or because of the date), this to be able to have a record in my BD of each generated file. I found something about JDBCAppender, but it doesn't help me because it listens to every log, I just want to listen when a new file is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Log4j 2.14.1 added a rollover listener you can use. It was added primarily to simplify unit testing but it will allow you to detect when new files are created. Just be careful to minimize what you do in the methods that get called. It provides a method that is called just before rollover and another for after the synchronous work is completed. If you have file compression enabled that happens asynchronously and may not be completed when the method is called. For this option you would implement [RolloverListener](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/index.html) and register the listener by calling addRolloverListener() on the RollingFileManager.

You could also create a custom action. They are evaluated on every rollover.

Answer (score -1):

WatchService allows you to monitor a directory for file changes. Check it out: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html

Register to watch a directory for creates:

```
private void registerDirectory(Path dir) throws IOException 
{
    WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE);
    keys.put(key, dir);
}
```

Comment: I think it would be too much, since every time it is written in the logs files, it would notify me.

Comment: Review, and I think it can be controlled, for when the file is created.

Comment: See this example: https://howtodoinjava.com/java8/java-8-watchservice-api-tutorial/  It shows how to filter on things like new files and changed files.